# How to use document.write inside html element dynamically

Tags: javascript, dom

currently i am using bellow code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      window.onload = function(){
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var html = "<html><body><p>this is" + 
          "<script>document.write('dynamic')<\/script> text.</p></body></html>";
      var doc = parser.parseFromString(html,'text/html');
      document.body.appendChild(doc.body.children[0]);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
    <body>
        <p>this is <script>document.write('dynamic')</script> text.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

that shows : this is dynamic text.

but currently i am loading page dynamicaly by ajax
and parsing using new DOMParser.
but it not prints "dynamic" only shows: this is  text.

Comment: That's how [`dw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) is designed to work. You can't use it to add content to a page after the page has been parsed, unless you don't want to re-write the whole document, including the head section. Use proper DOM manipulation methods instead.

Comment: Don't use `document.write` at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DOM manipulation methods shown [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createtextnode.asp):

```
var h = document.createElement("H1")                // Create a <h1> element
var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World");     // Create a text node
h.appendChild(t);
```

or [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp): `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";`

As you are currently loading the page via AJAX, you probably have to make sure that everything flows in the right order, i.e.: the change of the DOM is done after the page is received, etc. (Don't know your surrounding code, so I can't really speak to that).